How to set different colors for body and paper in mantine?
I've encountered an issue while working with Mantine UI library. When I set the background color of the body, the background color of the Paper component also changes to the same color. However, I want to have a grey background for the body and keep the Paper component's background color white.
here my app.css
:root[data-mantine-color-scheme="light"] {
  --mantine-color-body: grey !important;
}

Here is the current CSS for the Paper component:
.m_1b7284a3 {
    --paper-radius: var(--mantine-radius-default);
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: var(--paper-radius);
    box-shadow: var(--paper-shadow);
    background-color: var(--mantine-color-body);
}


Here the issue is,  CSS variable for the Paper component's background color is directly tied to the body background color. Therefore first add background color of the body separately.
    body {
  background-color: grey;
}

Now let's Override the Paper Background Color:
.mantine-Paper {
  background-color: white !important; 
}

